# Is it bad practice to git init in the $home directory to keep track of dot files?

Tags: configuration, home-directory, git

I want to backup and sync my dotfiles using github. Since all the dotfiles resides in $home by default, should I just `git init` in my $home folder, or is that a bad idea?

Having performed `git init` in $home, my idea is then to .gitignore all non-dotfiles and non-dotfolders.

Comment: Be careful what you sync to github, e.g. .ssh, .gnupg, etc.

Comment: I used to have a `$HOME/.git`, and I found it very cumbersome. A particular problem was cloning on other machines with populated home directories - I had no confidence that my existing files would not be clobbered. I am of the opinion that this is a strong argument in favour of the XDG Directory Spec, but many popular packages choose not to support it. Alas!

Comment: I'm appalled that several (most) of the responses do not answer the question of whether it is a good practice.

Comment: I have a repository in `~/skel` with the relevant files in it, and the corresponding files in `~` are symlinks to that. For directories like `.ssh`, I have a symlink to `~/skel/dotssh` and track the directory, with the appropriate `.gitignore` rules. This has served me well since around 2003 (back then using CVS).

Answer (score 62):

Create a "bare" git repository:

```
cd $HOME
git init --bare .dotfiles
```

> The `--bare` flag creates a repository that doesn’t have a working directory, making it impossible to edit files and commit changes in that repository.

Create an alias to manage the repository we just created:

```
alias dotfiles="/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME"
```

Ignore the files that are not being tracked from being shown up in `git status`:

```
dotfiles config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

Add your desired files:

```
dotfiles add .bash_aliases
```

Commit.

```
dotfiles commit -m 'Add .bash_aliases'
```

---

Now with the use of a `bare` repository, there is no `.git` directory in your `$HOME` directory; so it does not introduce any surprises while working with `git`.

That's how I manage my `dotfiles`. I first read about it [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/) years ago.

Comment: [Source](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init): "Conventionally, repositories initialized with the `--bare` flag end in `.git`." In the light of that convention, I think it would be better to do `git init --bare .dotfiles.git` as opposed to `git init --bare .dotfiles`.

Comment: +1, after trying several other approaches, I settled on using this, and it works very well for me. I even have the custom "dotfiles" command, just like you :D (for me it's a script, because it does some extra housekeeping)

Comment: @SebastianNielsen It's not a requirement. You can call them whatever you like.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Suffixing with `.git` is for when you want to use your `bare` repository as a remote centeral repository to "push" in or  "pull" from. Though it might be a good practice it's not really necessary. I'll rather to keep it as `.dotfiles` for simplicity.

Comment: [A related answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27336975) There, I note that this technique won't work with many git UI/porcelain.

Comment: what is the problem with the OP and just not tracking files you don't want to track?

Answer (score 15):

It is a good practice, but you should ignore all files by default and just add the files you need. Here is an example of a `.gitignore`:

```
# ignore all
*
# include dot files (including .gitignore)
!.*
```

You can also exclude other files putting other lines at the end of your .gitignore:

```
# ignore all
*
# include dot files (including .gitignore)
!.*
.ssh
```

Comment: will this not include : . (current dir) ?  .ssh (ssh directory, containing potentially private keys) ?

Comment: Yes, It will include. You shouldn't push to a public repository. Other option is to exclude specific files in a line below the one with the exclamation

Comment: Thx for the answer. Maybe add an edit to show how to do that, as it may save many people stumbling on the solution

Comment: @neves it could be useful to demonstrate how to ignore then `~/.ssh`, because to some it may not seem so trivial to switch back and forth between includes and excludes kind of rules.

Answer (score 12):

If you're slightly uneasy about having a git repository in your home folder (which I would be), you might consider this idea:

- Create a git repository somewhere else, e.g. `~/src/configuration` or `~/etc` or wherever you like.
- Put all your configuration files in there.
- Replace your configuration files (at the normal paths) with symlinks into this repository.
- Perhaps write a simple shell script which checks that the symlinks point where you expect them to, and run it e.g. daily in a cron job.

Every problem in computing can be solved with an additional layer of indirection ;-)

Comment: [chezmoi](https://www.chezmoi.io/) does *all* of the above if you set your config to `mode = "symlink"`. You can also configure it to use plain files and not symlinks. (You will need to set up a cronjob, but "checking" comes for free.)

Answer (score 10):

I'd say it is a bad practice, indeed. None of the tutorials at https://dotfiles.github.io/tutorials/ or https://github.com/webpro/awesome-dotfiles will have you track the home folder directly into a home-level git repository. Most will manually copy or symlink the files.

While git tracking your dotfiles is a great idea, having a git repo at home level makes it easy to accidentally run commands to that repo when you actually mean to run it in a more specific directory repository.

For example:

```sh
mkdir ~/Projects/my-awesome-web-app
cd ~/Projects/my-awesome-web-app
npm init # initializes node projects, creates package.json
git add package.json # would not fail, since it's actually inside a git repo
git commit -m "starts work" # actually commits to the home repo, not locally
```

Also, [Anish Athalye chooses *not* to track home folder directly under git](https://www.anishathalye.com/2014/08/03/managing-your-dotfiles/):

> - There is no possibility of accidentally deleting your files. With your entire home directory under version control, running something
>   like a git clean could wipe out everything in your home directory that
>   is not tracked by your VCS.
> - It is possible to track configuration files that belong somewhere other than $HOME.
> - Installing dotfiles on new machines is easier. All that is required is cloning your dotfiles followed by copying or linking files. Keeping
>   the entire home directory under version complicates installation.

Comment: That's not to say @ravexina's approach is wrong, but she has to go to some length to ensure it doesn't conflict with regular git usage.

Answer (score 8):

You could look at [yadm](https://yadm.io), it does mainly this but I guess it is more secure and the setup may be easier. I think it is just a wrapper of git at first (it does have more features though), meaning that you can just use usual git commands replacing `git` by `yadm` (like yadm add/clone/status etc.)

I am not affiliated to yadm, just a happy user.

Comment: Nice! I've been using homesick but looking to drop the ruby dependency.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for over 10 years has been a [repository with public configuration and code](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde). It includes a Makefile which does some basic checks and has an `install` target to create symbolic links in the home directory. This makes it harder to accidentally commit something which shouldn't be in there.

Comment: it seems like you don't actually run `git init` in the home folder, which is what OP asked about.

Comment: They asked whether that was a good idea. I've answered that.

Answer (score 1):

I do this, but have a whitelist of dotfiles, instead of including them all or having a blacklist.  That is, my .gitignore ignores everything and then un-ignores only those files and directories I want to include.

Example "whitelisting" .gitignore:

```
*
!.vimrc
!.gitignore
!.otherdotfile
```

etc

There are many dotfiles it doesn't make much sense to keep versioned, like things that are cached files, things that are updated dynamically by graphical apps, and so on.

Also consider that your repository will contain private information in areas you don't expect, even if you exclude things like your SSH keys.  Sharing this repository publicly is probably not a good idea.

Note also that if you have other git working trees in your home directory, you'll want the parent directories of those to be excluded from this repository so git doesn't start thinking they are sub-repositories or something.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using git, you may consider symlinking your dot files to a shared storage provider

- dropbox
- google drive
- keybase

There is a tool called mackup that will automatically create these symlinks and has support for a wide variety of other applications. Works on Linux and Mac

https://github.com/lra/mackup

Comment: you can symlink to a git repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to have the home directory git repository, simply because you run into weirdness with sub-directories of home also being git repos.

After playing with this idea I now selectively sync what I want sync'd into a project directory and use that as a place to make backups and restore from. That way there isn't a .git in the home directory.

Make a working directory wherever, and then place a `backup.sh` in it that looks something like this with any modifications you want (i.e. you may want to add your documents folder or whatnot)

```
#!/bin/sh

# = rsync stuff =
# ===============
# -a, --archive
# This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. 
# It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a notable omission).


rsync --mkpath -a ~/.icons ./home_archive
rsync --mkpath -a ~/.themes ./home_archive

rsync --mkpath -a ~/Pictures/1079333.png ./home_archive/Pictures/
rsync --mkpath -a ~/.config/xfce4 ./home_archive/config

rsync --mkpath -a ~/bin ./home_archive

rsync --mkpath -a ~/.profile ./home_archive
rsync --mkpath -a ~/.Xmodmap ./home_archive
rsync --mkpath -a ~/.zshrc ./home_archive
```

This will then sync what you want syncing into `home_archive`. To restore, from the parent directory of `home_archive`, use the command

`rsync --mkpath -a home_archive/* ~`

Downside is that you need enough disc space to make the clone, but it keeps things much cleaner.

If you want to use a more carpet bombing approach and then exclude things like with a gitignore, then rsync can be used like that also . .

`rsync -a --exclude '*.txt' --exclude 'dir3' --exclude 'dir4' sourcedir/ destinationdir/`